# Adding/Modifying Tomcat Library

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I want to create a web application with Java, Eclipse and Tomcat 9.0.8. But i see that the Tomcat server comes with few libraries compared to other servers. I need to use more libraries and maybe update some ones. I need to use more javaee libraries and maybe modify some that are already included in Tomcat.

Can i replace a library in the Tomcat lib folder? For example, i want to replace servlet-api.jar version 4.0.0 with the version 4.0.1.

Can i add more libraries to that folder? For example, javaee.jar?

Comment: Why do you want/need to do this?

Comment: For example. I want to add JSF libraries in lib folder, so i can specify in maven the jsf library as provided in every project i create. I'm just learning how tomcat works.

Comment: Just manage your dependencies entirely from your POM.  In the case of the Tomcat JARs, you may need to tell Maven that they are provided at runtime.  Other than this, don't tamper with Tomcat JARs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of "I *need* to ... update some [libraries]" (from your question) and "I'm just learning how tomcat works" (from your comment) sounds counter-intuitive to me.

Of course, you're free to change whatever you like on tomcat. You'll have to be aware though that nobody will have done the same thing and tested. And if you run into problems and intend to post any questions here or elsewhere, you should include the fact that you have replaced several libraries that tomcat was tested with.

There may or may not be a point for adding classes into the common classpath. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html advises against adding *application* classes there:

> Common — This class loader contains additional classes that are made
>   visible to both Tomcat internal classes and to all web applications.
>
> Normally, application classes should NOT be placed here. ...

That being said, yes, you can add classes there, and they'll be available to all webapplications. However, no update to any of these classes can be done at runtime - in contrast to applications contained in webapplications. Webapps can be redeployed within a running tomcat. Updates to classes in the common classloader require a tomcat restart.

As you mention that you'll also need javaee.jar, you might be happier with [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/), which bundles a few more jars compared to stock Tomcat.

Comment: Ok, so then the most reasonable thing is not to touch those libraries. What happen if i include a library dependency in Maven with -compile_ scope with a higher version than the one used by the Tomcat server? And sorry for that, I am not totally expressive in English, not even in my native language.

Comment: Do you need a specific feature from the younger version? Or do you just include it because it's there? The question is hard to answer in an abstract way. I revs to recommend asking on the tomcat mailing list for upgrade plans, or reasons to keep a particular version. Include the library in question in your inquiry. I'm not aware of differences between servlet 4.0.0 and 4.0.1. Language: works, no worries, not my native one as well.

Comment: I would say that I only want to use the most updated in everything, but as you said, stability is more important.